# ASP.NET - Set CheckBoxList input tag "class" attribute

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0, checkboxlist

I'm working with an asp.net 4.0 application and I am wondering if its possible to set the class attribute on the checkbox (the input tag) created by a checkbox list control.

What the following does is wrap the input tag in a span tag and apply the class to that:

```
foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
   li.Attributes.Add("class", "check-if-dirty");
}
```

Creates:

```
<span class="check-if-dirty"><input id="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$CheckBoxList1$0" value="a" /><label for="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0">a</label></span>
```

What I want is this:

```
<span><input class="check-if-dirty" id="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$CheckBoxList1$0" value="a" /><label for="MainContent_CheckBoxList1_0">a</label></span>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know jQuery isn't tagged on here, but here's some simple code that will accomplish that, if using this library happens to be an option for you.

```
$("span.check-if-dirty").each(function() {
    $(this).children("input").addClass("check-if-dirty");
});
```

There might be a way to get asp.net asp.net to do what you want by messing around in the PreRender part of the page lifecycle.  If this answer doesn't work for you, you might look into that.  Sorry I can't be a better help.

Comment: This is defintely the easiest way, apart from setting a CSS style at the top level - e.g. span input { style; } as a selector. Unfortunately, CheckBoxList is very annoying and doesn't expose InputAttributes like the humble Checkbox does, for example.

Comment: I implemented this and it works...so ill go with it! Thank you!

Comment: Yes jQuery works however, what about the code behind solution?

Comment: @Tom - what about it?  I don't have a code behind solution, as I said in the answer.  If you do, then by all means provide one.

Comment: All good @Adam, I don't have a solution which is why I was looking and commented on your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can do this as long as the class was just to set attributes on the checkbox and not for use as a selector for some JQuery. eg to set properties for a big checkbox:

css file:

```
.BigCheckbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelect" runat="server" CssClass="BigCheckbox"/>
```